# recording from vinyl to tape

Tags: recording, vinyl

I have a [Marantz](http://www.marantz.co.uk/uk/pages/home.aspx) record deck, a [Denon - DRM 540](http://www2.aerne.com/Public/dok-sw.nsf/0c6187bc750a16fcc1256e3c005a9740/ee0c636c49d624f7c1256dff007841d8/$FILE/DRM540_all.pdf) Tape deck and a [Marantz PM5004](http://www.audioholics.com/amplifier-reviews/marantz-5005-series-integrated-amp-cd-player) integrated amp.

I have been trying to record from vinyl to cassette with no success.

Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? e.g. Are you getting a signal to the tape deck? Do you have a needle installed?!

Answer (score -1):

The manaul of your tape deck has [instructions](http://www2.aerne.com/Public/dok-sw.nsf/0c6187bc750a16fcc1256e3c005a9740/ee0c636c49d624f7c1256dff007841d8/$FILE/DRM540_all.pdf) on how to record

From photos on the web I've seen it has 2 rca sockets on the back - this is what I presume input and output. Try connecting the vinyl output to the tape input here and selecting the proper source when recording